# I have Marklogic Count xquery that runs fine returning total count for the keyword. I am trying to run same query as CORB job

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-corb

I have Marklogic Count xquery that runs fine returning total count for the keyword. I am trying to run same query as CORB job, but result I am getting is count of each node. Do anyone has any idea to this please then share me idea.

Below query is what I am using.

```
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:word-query("Cirrus")))
```

Answer (score 1):

`xdmp:estimate` returns the number of documents (fragments) matched by a query, not the number of times a specific term matches within those documents. This happens very fast because MarkLogic is able to calculate the number using only indexes.

To count matches within a document, however, you have to load the complete document into memory before you can count the matching terms, which is much slower and memory intensive. If you try to perform that type of count on too many documents within a single query, you may blow the expanded tree cache (which is responsible for holding the full XML of documents read during queries), so it is important to carefully tune your CORB job to prevent that from happening.

Here is an example of how you might count all of the individual matches for a query within a result set:

```
sum(
  cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:word-query("Cirrus"))
    /cts:walk(., cts:word-query('Cirrus'), 1)
)
```

Comment: Hi, appreciate your details input on this and really helpful idea indeed. I am thinking to write word count script on top of text file corb job generates. Also trying with ModuleExecutor option as in https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/ModuleExecutor-Tool which looks to be better solution.

Comment: Hi @rawal, if this answers your question, please accept it by clicking the green check to the left.